# The number of items in dynamic module are not correct

Tags: c#-4.0, content-management-system, sitefinity

I created a dynamic module name "Staff Profiles". When I go to this module list I use the search function( please check detail in image: searchfunction.png)

[image]

Then I saw the result are not correct( please check in image file: results.png)

[image]

So please give me some ideas to fixed this.
Below is the machine information:

•   Operating System - Windows 8 64bit

•   Browser - Google Chrome

•   Browser Version - 48.0.2564.109 m

•   Database - Oracle 11.x

•   Severity - 3 - Question/Inconvenience

•   Sitefinity Edition - Standard License

•   Sitefinity Domain - nie.edu.sg

•   Issue Area - Administration

•   Version - 8.1 5820

•   Product - Sitefinity CMS

Comment: maybe you have a deleted Profile from this Department that is still in the Recycle Bin?

Comment: Thank for your reply but is not in recycle bin because I  delete it already, after sending the support ticket to Sitefinity Support Team I receive the message that is the bugs of Sitefinity Version - 8.1 5820 and they told me that they will fix it at version 8.2.5912.0